# FB button "like" is very slow

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I added the button "like" on the site, but in IE 9 was strongly inhibit asynchronous loading.

http://mallstreet.ru/en/369/gazonokosilki/bosch/51363/art-23-easytrim-accu.html

When I delete this one code from the page, the page loads quickly:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Having the same problem since last week.

Comment: same here. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to narrow this down to the emulateIE7 meta tag in the page head.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Once I removed that tag the performance improved on the facebook code.

Comment: right, I'm not positive yet but it does look like that works. Wonder why that would be.